# Changing the pointer inside a function does not reflect outside the function

Tags: c, pointers

```
void alloco(int *ppa)
{
    int i;
    printf("inside alloco %d\n",ppa);
    ppa = (int *)malloc(20);
    ppa[15] = 9;
    printf("size of a %d \n", sizeof(ppa));
    for(i=0;i<20;i++)
    printf("a[%d] = %d \n", i, ppa[i]);
}

int main()
{
    int *app = NULL;
    int i;
    printf("inside main\n");
    alloco(app);
    for(i=0;i<20;i++)
    printf("app[%d] = %d \n", i, app[i]);
    return(0);
}
```

Basically all I wanted to do is to pass a null pointer from my `main` to a function(`alloco`) which allocates memory/fills the same location the pointer is pointing to and returns. I am getting local prints correctly that is inside function(`alloco`) but not in `main`.

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: `ppa` is a local variable in function `alloco`. Setting `ppa = (int *)malloc(20)` does not affect the value of this variable outside that function.

Comment: `printf("inside alloco %d\n",ppa);` <-- Print pointers using `%p`

Comment: @CoolGuy Really useful info. Added into my answer. :-)

Comment: `printf("size of a %d \n", sizeof(ppa));` <-- Print `size_t` using `%zu`

Comment: @CoolGuy I guess i beat you in the last one. :P

Comment: The summary of your question ("Output of the following code sample") is rather unspecific and will hardly be found by users searching for a related problem. Could you find a better description?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need this:

```
void alloco(int **ppa)
{
    int i;
    printf("inside alloco %p\n",ppa);
    *ppa = malloc(20 * sizeof(int));
    (*ppa)[15] = 9;     // rather pointless, in the loop below (*ppa)[15] will be
                        // overwritten anyway
    printf("size of a %d \n", sizeof(*ppa));  // rather pointless, not sure
                                              // what you want to print here

    for(i = 0; i < 20; i++)
      printf("a[%d] = %d \n", i, (*ppa)[i]);
}

int main()
{
    int *app = NULL;  // you can drop the '= NULL', it's useless, because
    int i;            // alloco(&app) will change the value of app anyway
    printf("inside main\n");
    alloco(&app);

    for(i = 0; i < 20; i++)
      printf("app[%d] = %d \n", i, app[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

In *your* program you pass a pointer to `alloco` which will be in the `ppa` parameter. This `ppa` parameter is just like a local variable inside of `alloco` and when you modify it, the original value you passed to the function in `main`(`app`) won't be modified.

In the corrected version, we pass a *pointer* to `app`. In `alloco` we dereference that pointer and write the malloced value to it.

Comment: Standard Warning : Please [do not cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`. and some explanation will really do good. :-)

Comment: hi, i got the logic but when executed i get a core dump.
inside main
inside allocosize of a 4 
a[0] = 0 
a[1] = 9 
a[2] = -13543595 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: @Coder: I edited the program, it should be `(*ppa)[15]` instead of `*ppa[15]`.

Comment: Use `%p` to print pointers and `%zu` to print a `size_t` here:`printf("inside alloco %d\n",ppa);` and here `printf("size of a %d \n", sizeof(*ppa));` respectively. Crank up the warnings, Michael!

Comment: @michael Can you explain why is that? :)

Comment: @Coder , Because of operator precedence. You need to dereference the pointer before appyling the `[15]` operator.

Comment: as well as using the wrong format specifier, `printf("size of a %d \n", sizeof(*ppa));` is not very useful information. There's no way to retrieve how much space was malloc'd.

Comment: @MattMcNabb , Because it is the same as `printf("size of a %d \n", sizeof(int*));`?

Comment: @CoolGuy yes that's right

Answer (score 9):

`C` uses pass by value for function parameter passing. You can change the *value at address* pointed by `app` [i.e., `ppa`, in `alloco()`] from `alloco()`, but cannot change the value of `app`. In other words, `ppa` is local to function `alloco()`. Changing the value of `ppa` won't be affecting (reflected to) `app` present in `main()`.

If you want to change the value of `app` itself from `alloco()`, you need to pass a *pointer to* app (*Pointer-to-Pointer*).

Apart from this issue, in your code

```
ppa = (int *)malloc(20);
```

is wrong. What you wanted is actually

```
ppa = malloc(20 * sizeof (int)); // argument is in bytes, not in `int` or any elements
```

or, better,

```
ppa = malloc(20 * sizeof * ppa);  // data type integrity
```

It's worthy to mention that please [do not cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.

One more thing, while printing a *pointer*, use `%p` format specifier, while printing `size_t`, use `%zu`,  like

```
printf("inside alloco %p\n",ppa);
```

and

```
printf("size of a %zu\n", sizeof(ppa));  // sizeof returns size_t
```